# Why doesn't opencv's convexHull work on a subset of my contour, while it does work on the whole thing?

Tags: opencv, convex-hull

I'm trying to get the convex hull of a subset of a contour. I get the subset of the contour by slicing every nth point of the contour. OpenCV's convexHull works fine on the original contour, but throws an error when I try to run it on the subset.

```
a = contour
step = 5
b = contour[0::step]
a.shape, b.shape, a.dtype, b.dtype, a[0], a[-1], b[0], b[-1]
```

```
((1398, 1, 2),
 (280, 1, 2),
 dtype('int32'),
 dtype('int32'),
 array([[97, 33]], dtype=int32),
 array([[98, 33]], dtype=int32),
 array([[97, 33]], dtype=int32),
 array([[100,  33]], dtype=int32))
```

So you can see from the above that their shapes are almost the same, except that `b` has fewer points, and that their data types are the same, and that neither starts and finishes on the same exact point.

This works: `cv2.convexHull(a, returnPoints=False)`
This doesn't: `cv2.convexHull(b, returnPoints=False)`

The error I receive is:

```
error: OpenCV(4.8.0) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\convhull.cpp:143: error: (-215:Assertion failed) total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'cv::convexHull'
```

Comment: try with `b.copy()` instead. let me know if that works. can't do much without a [mre]